# C# and Objects/Classes

Tags: c#, oop, program-entry-point

I have tried to compile code from Deitel's C# 2010 for programmers. I copied it exactly out of the book, but it still can't find main, even though I declared it in one of the classes. Here is a look at the two classes:

For GradeBookTest:

```
// Fig. 4.2: GradeBookTest.cs
// Create a GradeBook object and call its DisplayMessage method.
public class GradeBookTest
{
// Main method begins program execution
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
// create a GradeBook object and assign it to myGradeBook
GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook();

// call myGradeBook's DisplayMessage method
   myGradeBook.DisplayMessage();
 } // end Main
 } // end class GradeBookTest
```

Now for the GradeBook class:

```
 // Fig. 4.1: GradeBook.cs
 // Class declaration with one method.
using System;

public class GradeBook
 {
 // display a welcome message to the GradeBook user
   public void DisplayMessage()
 {
 Console.WriteLine( "Welcome to the Grade Book!" );
 } // end method DisplayMessage
 } // end class GradeBook
```

That is how I copied them. Here is how they appeared in the book:

```
1 // Fig. 4.2: GradeBookTest.cs
2 // Create a GradeBook object and call its DisplayMessage method.
3 public class GradeBookTest
4 {
5 // Main method begins program execution
6 public static void Main( string[] args )
7 {
8 // create a GradeBook object and assign it to myGradeBook
9   GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook();
10
11 // call myGradeBook's DisplayMessage method
12  myGradeBook.DisplayMessage();
13 } // end Main
14 } // end class GradeBookTest
```

and

```
 // Fig. 4.1: GradeBook.cs
// Class declaration with one method.
using System;

public class GradeBook
{
// display a welcome message to the GradeBook user
public void DisplayMessage()
{
Console.WriteLine( "Welcome to the Grade Book!" );
} // end method DisplayMessage
} // end class GradeBook
```

I don't see why they are not working. Right now I am using Visual Studio Pro 2010. Any Thoughts?

Comment: Hi! After all this time, could you mark my answer as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You probably created the wrong type of project at Visual Studio. To be able tu **run** a project, it must be an application. This means it could be a web application, web site, windows application, console application and so on.

The easier for you to begin is with the console application. Open Visual Studio and point to File > New > Project > Visual C# > Windows > Console Application.
When you create it, you'll notice a Program.cs file. There you can find the main point of your application.

Tip: you might want to add another line below the call of DisplayMessage, which is

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Otherwise the prompt will close so fast that you won't be able to read it.

Good luck on your study!

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I created a console application, and the book told me to create another class for that app, a class so DisplayMessage could run, since it needed a Main to run. What I don't understand is that I did it according to the book , and it still is acting weird.

Comment: I figured it out. I think instead of adding a class, I might have added something that look slike it. Thanks for the help :)